# Python: searching for next column in the same loop [CSV]

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a spreadsheet with a column that goes: 1, 2, 3, 5... 100.

In my code I can search through each column. The column above is column 8. I want to be able to print a row value and the row below it. I have used:

```
print row[8 + 1]
```

All this seems to do is print the row value and then add one to it. However what I want to do is use:

```
print row[8]
print row[8 + 1]
```

Which would print out a value and the value underneath

Full code:

```
i

mport csv
import string

with open("testercsv.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #Error log file
    log_error = open("lewis.txt", 'a')
    #Checking row 
    next(f, None)
    next(f, None)
    for row in reader:
        #row 1
        if (row[1]) == "2":
            print "Found: ", "2"
        else:
            log_error.write("Found: ")
            log_error.write(row[1])
            log_error.write(" Expected: 2")
            log_error.write("\n")
        #row 2  
        if (row[2]) == "0":
            print "Found: ", "0"
        else:
            print "0 error"
        #row 3
        if (row[3]) == "LIVE":
            print "Found: ", "LIVE"
        else:
            print "LIVE error"
        #row 4  
        if (row[4]) == "2":
            print "Found: ", "2"
        else:
            print "2 error"
        #row 5  
        if (row[5]) == "0":
            print "Found: ", "0"
        else:
            print "0 error"
        #row 6
        if (row[6]) == "1":
            print "Found: ", "1"
        else:
            print "1 error"
        #row 7
        if (row[7]) == "0":
            print "Found: ", "0"
        else:
            print "0 error"
        #Checking count row 8

        print row[8+1]
```

Comment: How are you iterating over the csv file?

Comment: I have edited with my full code

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(0,100):
        print(row[i])
        print(row[i+1])
```

Comment: Where would I add this extra For loop?

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.